# How does one use FileStream to append to a file without an exclusive lock?

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream, filestream

What I'm trying to do with `FileStream` in C#/.NET is to open two streams: one appending to a file and the other reading those writes asynchronously (for unit testing some network connection handling code).  I can't figure out how to get the *writer* stream to open the file in non-exlusive locking mode and thus the code always throws an exception:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\test.txt' because it is being used
>   by another process.

Here's a smattering of code which demonstrates the issue:

```
FileStream fwriter = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Append,
    FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
FileStream freader = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this question: [C# file read/write fileshare doesn’t appear to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124946/c-file-readwrite-fileshare-doesnt-appear-to-work)

In short, your freader has to specify FileShare.Write to allow for the fact that there is already a writer on the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps, but if you are only unit testing, wouldn't it be easier to use a memory stream instead of files?

Comment: Yeah, if I could only figure out how to get a MemoryStream to act more like a connection.  Of course I'm still having just as much trouble with FileStream so I may ask another question to that effect.