# Sharing file locks

Tags: file, windows-services, concurrency, locking

I am currently working on a file processing service that looks at a fileshare, where files are uploaded to via FTP.

For scalability I've been asked to make this service to be able to be load balanced, so the service has to expect that other services on different machines may also be trying to process these files.

OK, so I thought I should be able achieve this by obtaining an exclusive lock for my process before processing a file, and skipping any files that may already be locked by another process.

The crux of this approach is shown below (I've left out the error handling for simplicity):

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Open(myFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, (FileShare.Read | FileShare.Delete))
{
//Do work
}
```

**Q1: My process now has a lock on this file. I thought this would mean I could then access the same file (without using the stream) and still have the correct access to it, but based on testing it seems I only have the benefits of the lock through the stream. Is this correct?**

(For example, before I included FileShare.Delete, File.Delete(myFile) failed)

The above lock ultimately uses the 'Write' permission to determine which service has the file, but is intended to allow other processes to still Read the file. This is because the process that has the lock attempts to verify if the file is a valid zip file , which uses a third party library (Xceed.Zip). However this fails saying the file *"is being used by another process"*. Using reflector I ultimately found the problematic call is:

```
stream = this.m_info.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Now I would have expected this to work as it only wants to read the file, but it fails. The reason appears to be outlined in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124946/c-file-read-write-fileshare-doesnt-appear-to-work). However, as this is a 3rd party API I can't change their code to use ReadWrite.

**Q2: Is there a way I can correctly lock the file so it will not be picked up by the other services, but it can still be verified as a zip file using the external API?**

I feel like there should be a 'correct' way to do this, but at the moment the best I can come up with is to lock the file, move it away from the shared directory, and then verify it at the new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning to reactively handle this situation by handling UnauthorizedAccessException I think you're making a serious mistake.

This can be handled by proactively renaming files. For example you can configure your service to only read files whose name is in the format 'Filename.YYYYMMDD.txt'. Prior to processing the file, you can rename it to 'Filename.YYYYMMDD.processing'. Then after processing the file you rename it to 'Filename.YYYYMMDD.done'.

You can even take it a step further by making another service that enqueues the filenames. This service will be a FileSystemWatcher that listens for FileAdd operations. Once it receives that event it proceeds to queueing the Filename to a global message queue. Then, each of your service will just be dequeueing filenames and no longer have to worry about concurrent access.

HTH

Comment: Accepted as the alternative solution is sound. To answer my own questions:

Q1: Yes. The lock is only for the stream, not the process
Q2: No. Alternatives must be considered.